# Pushforward of a Cohen-Macaulay module

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $f \colon R \to S$ be a homomorphism between (local Noetherian) rings which turns $S$ into a finitely generated $R-$module and let $M$ be a finitely generated over $S$.

Is $M$ is Cohen-Macaulay over $S$ if and only if $M$ is Cohen-Macaulay over $R$? Is $\text{depth}_R(M) = \text{depth}_S(M)$?

Comment: Yes to both questions. Unfortunately (?) the only reference I know is in french: Bourbaki, *Algèbre commutative* X, §2, Proposition 8.

Comment: Another way to see this easily is to notice that $H^i_{m_R}(M) = H^i_{m_S}(M)$ since under your hypotheses $\sqrt{m_R S} = m_S$.  Then use the description of depth via local cohomology vanishing.

Comment: Also, see https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUK for the statement on depth.